# Generalize a theorem about the $\mu$-measurability of a $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space. Let $f \in E^X$.

- $f$ is called $\mu$-***simple*** if $f = \sum_{k=1}^n e_k 1_{A_k}$ where $0 \neq e_k \in E$ and $(A_k)_{k=1}^n$ is a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint sets with finite measure in $\mathcal A$. Let $\mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$ be the space of such $\mu$-simple functions.
- $f$ is called $\mu$-***measurable*** if $f$ is a $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence $(f_n)$ in $\mathcal S (X, \mu, E)$.

Several months ago, I posted a proof  of below theorem

> [Theorem 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306628/the-mu-a-e-limit-of-a-sequence-of-mu-measurable-function-is-mu-measura) Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be complete and $\sigma$-finite, $(f_n)$ a sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions, and $f \in E^X$ the $\mu$-a.e. limit of $(f_n)$. Then $f$ is also $\mu$-measurable.

The proof of **Theorem 1** relies on both assumptions **completeness** and **$\sigma$-finiteness**. Now I want to prove **Theorem 2** which generalizes **Theorem 1** by removing the requirements **completeness**.

> **Theorem 2:** Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be $\sigma$-finite, $(f_n)$ a sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions, and $f \in E^X$ the $\mu$-a.e. limit of $(f_n)$. Then $f$ is also $\mu$-measurable.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt:** The proof relies on **Lemma 2**.

> [Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507633/completing-a-measure-space-does-not-affect-the-strong-measurability-of-a-functio) Let $(X, \mathcal A', \mu')$ be the completion of $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$. A function $f \in E^X$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if $f$ is $\mu'$-measurable.

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions and $f \in E^X$ the $\mu$-a.e. limit of $(f_n)$. Let $(X, \mathcal A', \mu')$ be the completion of $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$. Then $(X, \mathcal A', \mu')$ is complete and $\sigma$-finite. Because $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal A'$ and $\mu' \restriction \mathcal A = \mu$, we get

- $(f_n)$ is a sequence of $\mu'$-measurable functions,
- and $f \in E^X$ the $\mu'$-a.e. limit of $(f_n)$.

By **Theorem 1**, $f$ is $\mu'$-measurable. The claim then follows from **Lemma 2**. This completes the proof.

Comment: Theorem 2 is not true. Take for example $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R),m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let $\mathcal N$ be a non Borel nul set. Then you have that $m-$a.e $f_n(x):=\frac{1}{n}\to \boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N}(x)$, but $\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N}$ is not measurable.

Comment: @Surb I could not see how $f_n \to 1_\mathcal N$ $\mu$-a.e. Could you provide a Borel set $A \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R)$ such that $m(A) = 0$ and $f_n \to 1_\mathcal N$ on $A^c$. I also could not see how $1_\mathcal N$ is not $m$-measurable. Please notice that my definition of $\mu$-measurability is not the same as $(\mathcal A, \mathcal B (\mathbb R))$-measurability.

Comment: because $\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N}=0$ a.e. Therefore $\frac{1}{n}\to 0=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N}$ a.e. Your definition of $\mu-$measurability doesn't work if the space is not complete. The example I provide previously is a good counter-example (at least you can easily adapt it to find a counter example w.r.t. your definition).

Comment: @Surb It seems to me that $1_{\mathcal N}$ is $m$-measurable in my definition. It follows from [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506531/prove-that-if-n-is-a-null-set-in-mathbbrn-then-there-exists-a-borel-nul) that there is a Borel $m$-null set $N$ such that $\mathcal N \subset N$. Let $g_n := 1_N$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Then $g_n$ is $m$-simple and that $g_n \to 1_{\mathcal N}$ on $N^c$. Hence $g_n \to 1_{\mathcal N}$ $m$-a.e. Hence $1_{\mathcal N}$ is $m$-measurable.

Comment: Seems all correct, although I have to say that I didn't check your proof of the lemma. Which book (if any) are you using, BTW?

Comment: Thank you so much @PhoemueX. The proof of *Lemma 2* is actually very short and straightforward. I'm using [Analysis III](https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-III-Herbert-Amann-ebook/dp/B00KTHAJ7S/) by Amann. *Theorem 1* actually comes from the same book.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}\to\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N}$ when $n\to \infty $$m-$a.e. (where $\mathcal N$ is a non borel nul set) but $\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N}$ is not Borel measurable... so, I don't see how your theorem 2 can be true without completness of the $\sigma  -$algebra...

Comment: @Surb My definition of $\mu$-measurability does not require a function to be Borel measurable... On the other hand, being $\mu$-measurable and being Borel measurable are equivalent under some conditions. Please see [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306079/a-function-f-is-mu-measurable-if-and-only-if-f-is-mathcal-a-measurable). I'm pretty sure that you know it :v

Comment: You take at the very beginning an unspecified space $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$. The example I took in my previous comment is $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R),m)$ for $m$ being the Lebesgue measure. Therefore, in this space, being measurable means being Borel measurable. So, no, your theorem 2 is wrong in general, at least if you don't have completeness of the $\sigma -$algebra.

Comment: @Surb In my definition of $\mu$-measurability, $f$ is called $\mu$-measurable if $f$ is a $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence $(f_n)$ of $\mu$-simple functions. I already defined what being a $\mu$-simple function means. As you can see, I do **not** require $f^{-1} (O) \in \mathcal A$ for $O \in \mathcal B(E)$. As such, I don't think your sentence "...being measurable means being Borel measurable..." makes sense.

Comment: That's exactly why your definition of being measurable is wrong **without completeness**. Your definition of being measurable only makes sense if the $\sigma -$algebra is complete.

Comment: @Surb My definition of $\mu$-measurability is exactly the same as in the standard reference *Vector Measures* by Diestel/Uhl. Please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oDXc.png) for a screenshot of the definition I take from this textbook. As you can see they define $\mu$-measurability for arbitrary finite measure space.

Comment: As written on the first link of your document : $(\Omega ,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a finite measure space, and thus, obviously $\sigma -$finite. Therefore, the definition of $f$ being measurable if it's the $\mu-$a.e. limit of a simple sequence $(f_n)$ works. Moreover, seeing again your theorem 2, you add the hypothesis of $\sigma -$finitude, and thus, as I said from the very beginning, the result holds. However, the $\sigma -$finitude was not mention at the moment where I saw your post, and this hypothesis was crucial... but now, indeed, things are completely correct.

Comment: @Surb Thank you so much for your elaboration. It seems to me that the $\sigma$-finiteness is already there from the beginning. You can check this by looking at the edit history.

Comment: @Surb I have just posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508832/how-does-professor-amann-conclude-that-corollary-1-5-remains-true-for-incomplet) about how the completeness of a measure space affects the Borel measurability of a function. I hope that you can help me answer it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In a rigorous way, the concept of strong measurability doesn't apply to individual functions, but to equivalence classes of functions (defined by $=$a.e.). **Strong measurability is different from measurability**. If  $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ is not complete and $(X, \mathcal A', \mu')$ is its completion, then there is $C \in \mathcal A' \setminus \mathcal A$. So the function $1_C$ is a $\mu'$-measurable, but it is not $\mu$-measurable. However, $1_C$  is $\mu'$-strong measurable and it is also $\mu$-strong measurable. In fact, there is $B \in \mathcal A$ such that $1_C=1_B$ a.e.

Comment: @Ramiro In Diestel-Uhl's *Vector Measures*, the definition of $\mu$-measurability applies to all functions, not just to their equivalence classes. Please see their definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546351/extend-pettiss-measurability-theorem-to-sigma-finite-measure-spaces).

Comment: @Akira The issue here is just a confusion of terminology.   The definition of $\mu$-measurability in Diestel-Uhl's Vector Measures, does not distinguish between functions that are a.e. equal. Also that definition is **not** equivalent to the standard definition of measurability used for real or complex valued measures.

Comment: @Ramiro Yess, I agree. There is a [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306079/a-function-f-is-mu-measurable-if-and-only-if-f-is-mathcal-a-measurable) connecting them...

Answer (score 1):

I will use a *social argument* to disprove your *Lemma 2*.

First, notice that being $\mu'$-measurable is just the same as being measurable in the completed $\sigma$=algebra, as [you have stated in another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508832/how-does-professor-amann-conclude-that-corollary-1-5-remains-true-for-incomplet/).

If *Lemma 2* was true, that would kind of make the whole *$\mu$-measurable concept* a little *useless* as it would simply be the same as measurable over the completed $\sigma$-algebra. If *Lemma 2* is true, I would reinforce my comment that this is a very horrible definition of $\mu$-measurable. :-)

Comment: In contrast, I feel that *Lemma 2* makes the definition of $\mu$-measurability more appealing. First, adding more null sets to your $\sigma$-algebra is meaningless, which is consistent with the fact that values of a function on a null set does not affect its integral. Second, the space of "measurable" functions is enlarged and is strictly bigger than that of Borel measurable functions. Finally, it gives us some kind of invariance property :)

Comment: I would like to mention a previous comment by @Surb about my proof, i.e., "...but now, indeed, things are completely correct", to convince you that *Lemma 2* is indeed correct.

Comment: @Akira , In a rigorous way, the concept of strong measurability doesn't apply to individual functions, but to equivalence classes of functions (defined by $=$a.e.). **Strong measurability is different from measurability**. If  $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ is not complete and $(X, \mathcal A', \mu')$ is its completion, then there is $C \in \mathcal A' \setminus \mathcal A$. So the function $1_C$ is a $\mu'$-measurable, but it is not $\mu$-measurable. However, $1_C$  is $\mu'$-strong measurable and it is also $\mu$-strong measurable. In fact, there is $B \in \mathcal A$ such that $1_C=1_B$ a.e.